# Using the Math.pow() method inside of setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my example of reactjs code the method Math.pow() must change the value of div element on every click of button, but the method doesn't work, explain me, please, why.

```
handlerButton=(e)=> {           
   this.setState(function(prevState) {
   return({number: Math.pow(prevState.number, 2)});     
    }); 
}
```

Comment: `prevState.number` is a string, parse it to a number before passing it to `Math.pow`

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky it doesn't matter.

Comment: Please include all relevant code (which would include the HTML and JS) **in the question itself** not only on an external site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<MyButton handlerButton={this.handlerButton}/>
```

You're passing in a prop named `handlerButton`, but you never use props.handlerButton inside MyButton. Instead, you're using props.onClick

```
render() { 
    return <button id="btn" className="mybutton" onClick={this.props.onClick}>pow</button>;  
}
```

You need to use the same prop name in both places.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<MyButton handlerButton={this.handlerButton}/>
```

to :

```
<MyButton onClick={this.handlerButton}/>
```